# App Store Feedback Question

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, appstore-approval

We received the following email for our new app submitted a week ago.  Got a few questions:  Anyone know what the "information needed" part means?  Does this send us to the back of the queue - once we submit the requested data?

> ===============================
>
> Hello ,
>
> Thank you for submitting DG to the App
>   Store.
>
> We've completed the review of your
>   app, but cannot post this version to
>   the App Store because it did not
>   comply with the App Store Review
>   Guidelines, as detailed below:
>
> - 3.4: App names in iTunes Connect and as displayed on a device should be
>     similar, so as not to cause confusion
> - Information Needed
>
> To reply to this message or to get
>   more information, visit the Resolution
>   Center in iTunes Connect. Do not reply
>   directly to this email.
>
> Regards,
>
> App Review

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you go back to the queue (and also need to upload a new version).
I'm not sure regarding the "Information needed" but does your app require a login? If so, have you gave them a login name + password to use?

Apple won't really say if they checked everything, but I did encounter situations in the past where I was rejected about stuff like "keywords" and the whole process again took the usual amount of time. There were also cases where my update got approved in 2 hrs. after submission,  so just hope for the best and keep calm, there's nothing more you can do.

Comment: Thanks.  Have you encountered situations where they tell you problem A, and then you fix B and resubmit.  And then they tell you problem B.  When both A and B were in the original version?  How can you tell i'm not calm? ;)  If i had 15 reputation, i'd vote your answer up!

Comment: I've even encountered situations where there was a problem to overseen and bizar rejection reasons. I'm not sure I understood the whole A/B scenario you asked about, but just fix what they asked and resubmit. I think each time a different tester gets your app and that's why it can always be different

Answer (score 0):

Visit the Resolution Center in iTunes Connect. That is the best way to get in contact with them. You get there from the screen in iTunes Connect where you filled out the metadata before you submitted the app for review.